# npm error cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'

Tags: vue.js, npm, babeljs

I am currently going through a video tutorial on how Vue works and am just learning the basics of components and setting it all up. Yesterday everything was going just fine, I could run

```
npm run serve
```

and it would start up no issues. I loaded up the project today to continue on with the tutorial and when I went to run serve again I ran into an issue

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
```

followed by the stack. I tried to run

```
npm install @vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset --save-dev
```

but that gives me the error

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'B:\Users\...\vue-practice-traversy\@vue\cli-plugin-babel\preset\package.json'
```

I can't seem to figure out what is happening exactly. I installed the vue cli again and ran npm install but still get the same errors. I don't even know exactly what code I can show you because I'm not sure where the error is happening or what is causing it to break. The only thing I did between yesterday and right before I tried running it was add json server as the tutorial was doing that as well. I started up VSCode, started up json server, and then tried to start up the vue project. Let me know what I can show to help or what I am missing as to why it won't start up for me anymore. Thank you in advance for the help!

Edit: removed node modules and package-lock.json and did npm install again. This fixed the issue commented below about vue being a missing dependency. Now am getting compile error of

```
Syntax error: TypeError: cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined
```

Still having issues figuring that out right now, have tried removing node modules and package-lock.json again but still same error.

Answer (score 14):

You can try:

`npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env`

After that you have to update your babel config. Use @babel/preset-env instead of babel-preset-env :

```
"presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env"
]
```

Comment: I attempted this and it did get further into the process of starting the dev server but errors at 98% with error of dependency not found: * vue in ./src/main.js to install it you can run: npm install --save vue. I tried running the command suggested, it went through with no errors but doesn't seem to have fixed the issue because running serve again errors out with the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

deleting `package-lock.json` and `npm install` again worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check your packages are installed (node_modules FOLDER exists):
To install the node_modules packages :

> npm install

Answer (score 1):

The error message is slightly misleading, as some code is importing a folder in the module instead of the module itself. The actual module you want to install is

```
@vue/cli-plugin-babel
```

So,

```
npm i @vue/cli-plugin-babel -D
```

should do the trick. Did for me anyways.